# Comparing two lists. How to check each index of my answer list and check if each index is the same as the index of my other answer list

Tags: python, list

I have made a program that opens a txt doc and readlines it into a list. I created a variable with answers. How can I compare each indexed answer from my answers list to my student answers list?

Here is the code that I tried:

```
answers = ['A','C','A','A','D','B','C','A','C','B','A','D','C','A','D','C','B','B','D','A']


def main():

    #Open the student test scores for reading.

    infile = open("C:\\Users\mrsac\OneDrive\Desktop\CS 202 Files\Module 2\Module 2 Assignment Folder\studentanswers1.txt",'r')

    #Read contents of studentanswers1.txt into a list.

    student_answers = infile.readlines()

    #Close the file.

    infile.close()

    #Strip the \n character from each element in the list.

    index = 0

    while index < len(student_answers):

        student_answers[index] = student_answers[index].rstrip('\n')

        index += 1

    #Compare the answers and the student_answers for similar indexes characters

    for i in range(len(student_answers)):

        if (student_answers[i]==answers[i]):

            correct_answers = 0

            correct_answers += 1

            print('You answered ', correct_answers, 'questions correctly.')

            if correct_answers >= 15:

                print('You passed the exam!')

            else:

                print('You did not pass the exam.')





main()
```

Comment: The highest value that *correct_answers* could ever have is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are zeroing the correct answers each time you find a correct answer

```
if (student_answers[i]==answers[i]):

    correct_answers = 0
```

You should also print the results after your for loop ends. Your indentation prints the result inside the loop, each time it finds a correct answer:

```
answers = ['A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C',
           'B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'A']


def main():

    # Open the student test scores for reading.

    with open("C:\\Users\mrsac\OneDrive\Desktop\CS 202 Files\Module 2\Module 2 Assignment Folder\studentanswers1.txt", 'r') as infile:
        student_answers = infile.readlines()

    correct_answers = 0

    for correct_answer, student_answer in zip(answers, student_answers):

        # Compare the answers and the student_answers for similar indexes characters
        if correct_answer in student_answer.upper():

            correct_answers += 1

    print('You answered ', correct_answers, 'questions correctly.')

    if correct_answers >= 15:

        print('You passed the exam!')

    else:

        print('You did not pass the exam.')


main()
```

Comment: Thank you! My main issue was my counter like you mentioned and then I changed my indentation for my print blocks and it works like I want it to!

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer with explanation as and where it is required.

```
answers = ['A','C','A','A','D','B','C','A','C','B','A','D','C','A','D','C','B','B','D','A']

def main():

    #delclare variable 'correct_answer' with value 0
    correct_answer = 0
    
    infile = "C:\\Users\mrsac\OneDrive\Desktop\CS 202 Files\Module 2\Module 2 Assignment Folder\studentanswers1.txt"
    
    #by using 'with open' method you don't need to close the file again
    with open(infile, 'r') as fl:
        #create a list of all lines
        x = fl.readlines()
        
        for i in range(len(x)):
        
            #As each answer ends with a new line, add \n with after each answer
            if x[i] == f'{answers[i]}\n':
                correct_answer = correct_answer + 1
    
    #use return command as this is a function. 'print' is just to ensure the output
    if correct_answer >= 15:
        return 'You passed the exam!'
    else:
        return 'You did not pass the exam.'
        
r = main()
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing two lists, the ideal function to use is the built-in *zip()*

```
answers = [
    "A",
    "C",
    "A",
    "A",
    "D",
    "B",
    "C",
    "A",
    "C",
    "B",
    "A",
    "D",
    "C",
    "A",
    "D",
    "C",
    "B",
    "B",
    "D",
    "A",
]

FILENAME = r"C:\Users\mrsac\OneDrive\Desktop\CS 202 Files\Module 2\Module 2 Assignment Folder\studentanswers1.txt"

with open(FILENAME) as data:
    if sum(a == b for a, b in zip(answers, map(str.rstrip, data))) >= 15:
        print("You passed the exam")
    else:
        print("You did not pass the exam")
```

**Note:**

The expression *a == b* in the generator equates (obviously) to either True or False. When either of these bool values are used in a numeric context they equate to 1 and 0 respectively